# QDoubleSpinBox signals valueChanged before the edit is completely done

Tags: qt

I have a QDoubleSpinBox in my GUI. The problem is the valueChanged is always called while the user is typing his input in it. This will run the valueChanged everytime and user is not able to write the values he wants to. Is there any way to get rid of this behavior and call valueChanged right after the value is completely changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://forum.qt.io/topic/1688/solved-qspinbox-how-to-signal-only-when-editing-finished/2

Summary:  turn off [keyboard tracking](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking-prop)

Comment: This, of course, depends on you finding the Qt definition of "completely changed" to be acceptable (loss of focus, Enter keypress, or spinbox arrow press).